# Does Super gradients model freezes?

Tags: pytorch, artificial-intelligence, freeze

How to freeze your model in super gradients? Is it possible? like model.trainable=(False)

I want to know how to freeze my baseline model?

model = models.get('yolo_nas_l', num_classes=1, pretrained_weights='coco')

I know the num_classes=1 id doing replacing the head and it needs
to train, Should i freeze some layers? if it says yes? how to freeze layers?